# pass down a published var from an generic interactor that conforms to protocol

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols

I am using SomeView in many places with different interactors, so it uses a general interactor that conforms to protocol InteractorProtocol. The problem is SomeView has several SomeButton views which take @Binding as argument and I can't pass down my someState1 and someState2 variables to SomeButton. I could pass my Interactor down to SomeButton and use the interactor variables there, but it feels wrong. Is there a way around this? Could the solution for the interactor maybe be different to make this work?

```
protocol InteractorProtocol {
    var someState1: Bool { get set }
    var someState1Published: Published<Bool> { get }
    var someState1Publisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher { get }

    var someState2: Bool { get set }
    var someState2Published: Published<Bool> { get }
    var someState2Publisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher { get }

}

class SomeInteractor: ObservableObject & InteractorProtocol {
    @Published var someState1 = true
    var someState1Published: Published<Bool> { _someState1 }
    var someState1Publisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher { $someState1 }

    @Published var someState2 = true
    var someState2Published: Published<Bool> { _someState2 }
    var someState2Publisher: Published<Bool>.Publisher { $someState2 }

}

struct SomeView<Interactor: InteractorProtocol & ObservableObject>: View {
    @ObservedObject var interactor: Interactor

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            SomeButton(selected: self.interactor.$someState1) // not allowed
            SomeButton(selected: self.interactor.$someState2) // not allowed
        }
    }
}

struct SomeButton: View {
    @Binding var selected: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Text("text...")
        .background(selected ? Color.green : Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not directly related, but if `SomeButton` doesn't change the `selected` binding, it need not be a binding at all - just a normal property.

Comment: Good point but it actually changes when clicked, just didn’t include it in the example

Comment: What exactly is the error when you say "not allowed"?

Comment: this is the error: Cannot convert value of type 'Published<Bool>.Publisher' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'

Comment: Also, you don't actually need `someState1Published`, and also likely not `someState1Publisher`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
protocol InteractorProtocol: ObservableObject {
   var someState1: Bool { get set }
   // ...
}

class SomeInteractor: InteractorProtocol {
   @Published var someState1: Bool = true
   // ...
}

struct SomeView<Interactor: InteractorProtocol>: View {
   @ObservedObject var interactor: Interactor

   var body: some View {
      HStack {
         SomeButton(selected: self.$interactor.someState1)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: same error as mentioned in the comment below the question